# Windows Phone SDK - XAML - automatic margin for the top margin

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have the following `XAML` in `my Windows Phone app`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" />
    <TextBlock name="NameBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" Margin="150,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" />
    <TextBlock name="DescriptionBlock" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="25" Margin="150,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" />
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Currently, I have the margin of the second TextBlock (`DescriptionBlock`) set to a static value. Now because I have the work wrapping of the first `TextBlock` (`NameBlock`) set to `"Wrap"`, the height of the `TextBlock` is variable.

**Does anyone know how to make the top-margin of `DescriptionBlock` equal to the automatic height of `NameBlock`?** This would ensure that the second DescriptionBlock appears directly below the `NameBlock`, regardless of the length of the text of `NameBlock`.

Many thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what panels are for. Wrap the two text blocks in stack panel and it will stack the text blocks one above the other.

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" />
        <StackPanel Margin="150,20,0,0" Width="300">
            <TextBlock name="NameBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30"  TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock name="DescriptionBlock" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

A panel that holds a single child is usually useless, so I removed the stack panel around the grid.

If you'd like to continue using `Grid` you can define rows for it to size automatically.

Comment: That did the trick! I guess I just had my ordering incorrect in my head. Many thanks!